# Open function in C says unable to open device: permission denied

Tags: c++, sudo, hid

I've been messing with `hidraw.h` to see what I could do with my USB but when I try to open `/dev/hidraw0` it says `Unable to open device: Permission denied`, I know I could do something like `system("sudo open /dev/hidraw0");`
But of course it wouldn't have the same effect. Also I'm in Kali Linux. Here's my code:

```
/* Linux */
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/hidraw.h>

/* Unix */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* C */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int fd;
    int i, res, desc_size = 0;
    char buf[256];
    struct hidraw_report_descriptor rpt_desc;
    struct hidraw_devinfo info;

    fd = open("/dev/hidraw0", O_RDWR);

    if(fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Unable to open device");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Something happend!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all you should try running your program with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program doesn't have permission to open `/dev/hidraw0`. So you need to run it in such a way that it has permission.

The simplest way to do that, as ForceBru's comment suggests, is to run the program itself under `sudo`. (You can't run just the `open` function under `sudo`; `open` is a function, not a program.)

You might also be able to make the program run with root privileges by setting its `setuid` flag, using `chmod u+s` or `chmod u+gs`.

Consider that the device has the permissions it has for what are presumably good reasons. Be careful.

Comment: You can use `setcap` to give more fine-grained permissions than full root access.

Comment: I had to go to the directory it was in and type `sudo ./CPP` and it worked! And even better my computer didn't crash! :)

Answer (score 0):

If possible then first try to give some more permission to that device

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/hidraw0
```

then run you program. if required then also try changing its owner by `Chown` command.

Comment: Changing the permissions on the device is almost certainly a bad idea. I don't know what `/dev/hidraw0` is, but presumably it has the permissions it has for a reason. Giving every user on the system permission to read, write, and execute (!) it is dangerous. Give the *program* permission to access the device.

Comment: Keep in mind I just downloaded Kali yesterday on a USB and have very little experience with it's command line and interface. So how would I go about giving my program permission to access it? And if you don't mind how would I go about identifying what `/dev/hidraw0` is?

Comment: You should use udev to set the permissions, but you should probably make it group-based rather than letting world do it.